# How do I display my custom menu in administrative menu?

Tags: 7, routes

In my D7 website, I want to display my own custom menu in administrative menu (as in Dashboard, Content, etc.,).

I want those custom menu's available only for particular roles. How can I achieve this functionality without lot of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats Easy. You need to goto `structure >> menus >> Management`. From there you can click on `add link` and add the menu link in that , it will automatically get added to the administrative menu toolbar.

Making that to be visible for specific roles , you need to give permission for `overlay` in that you need to enable this permission for that role `Access the administrative overlay`.

That will make your menu appear as administrative menu for what ever role you specified in permission tab of admin.

Comment: thanks Ram. I tried and it worked :). But its also showing content menu and shortcut menu. Is it possible to disable those?

Comment: @pown: Thats a tricky one :). If i was doing this task, then i will hide it using css.  If i try to hide it using generic css, even admin role will also get that menu as  hidden.

So in order to avoid that , i may add role as a class name in the body class. so with that as parent i will hide the menus which are not required to show on corresponding logins :)

Comment: wow.. I think it'll work. Thanks for the suggestion.